# How could I turn off decompilation of the files in the Rider?

Tags: c#, ide, decompiling, rider

How could I turn off decompilation of the files in the Rider? It drives me crazy that every time I place a breakpoint somewhere and start to move upward the stack trace the rider provides me with decompiled version of my files instead of original one. And nothing is said how to turn it off on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in Rider settings search for "Enable external source debug"

Answer (score 0):

In Rider 2021.1, the accepted answer didn't direct me to the setting, so I assume it moved.

Now you can find the setting under `Tools > External Symbols > Decompile methods`.

Answer (score 0):

Rider 2022.3.2
if you dont want decompile external codes

simply untick **Enable external source debug** checkbox as below

[image]